# SQL get all records except where name = variable

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables 'movie', 'movie_country_restriction', 'countries'.
So for example I have a movie and that movie is restricted in the US.

Here's an example with dummy data:

> movie
>
> id - name
>
> 96 - movie A
>
> 97 - movie B
>
> 98 - movie C

---

> movie_country_restriction
>
> movieId - countryId
>
> 98 - 61
>
> 96 - 24
>
> 96 - 61
>
> 97 - 1

---

> countries
>
> id - name
>
> 1 - france
>
> 24 - usa
>
> 61 - germany

Now my goals is to select all movies but leave out the ones with a restriction.

### EDIT

So my goals is to get 'Movie B' and 'Movie C' since there is no restriction on those in the USA. If I use germany as paramater I should get only 'Movie B' since movie A and B are restricted in germany

Here is the query that I have now. It works but as soon as there are multiple countries restricted on 1 movie it doesn't work.

```
$query = 'SELECT m.* FROM movie m ' .
            'INNER JOIN movie_country_restriction mcr ON m.id = mcr.countryId ' .
            'INNER JOIN countries c ON c.id = mcr.countryId ' .
            'WHERE c.name = ? ' .
        ;
```

I was thinking I should use an outer join but I am not sure if it's the best way to appreoach this.

Any help is appreciated realy!

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Use an outer join. Have a look at some examples

Comment: @Strawberry can you point me to some good examples with 3 tables all examples are using only 2 tables

Comment: Change the word 'INNER' to 'LEFT'. Change the word 'WHERE' to 'AND'. Add the line 'WHERE c.name IS NULL.

Comment: i suggest you to use a NOT IN

Comment: @Strawberry I am sorry but I don't think that what you're suggesting is correct. Thanks for you answer and help !

Comment: Apology accepted. Obviously, it's not really gameid, so you have to fix that bit too

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for pointing that out! So you have no idea how to fix my query? I have searched for some outer join exmaples but can't seem to find any that are similar to my situation, unfortunately.

Comment: An appropriate answer would be exactly as I have described - but obviously with the mistakes in your code corrected ;-) (Why would country_id relate to movie_id ?!?!?!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the data you have supplied, an answer could be

```
SELECT * FROM movie m
  WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT movieID from movie_country_restriction mcr
                       LEFT JOIN countries c ON mcr.countryID=c.id
                       WHERE c.name LIKE 'USA')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48603b/2)

One mistake in your code was in the first join, where you used m.id = mcr.countryId

Also, to get all movies not blocked, you can not use inner joins.

**EDIT**
I have changed my answers according to your comments.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer!, unfortuantely it doesn't work. A movie can be resitricted in multiple countries I updated my OP with more example data to demonstrate

Answer (score -1):

Try this, Hope it will help.

```
$query = 'SELECT m.* FROM movie m ' .
            'LEFT JOIN movie_country_restriction mcr ON m.id = mcr.countryId '.
            'LEFT JOIN countries c ON c.id = mcr.countryId ' .
            'WHERE c.name not in ( select distinct name from countries)' .
        ;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it doesn't work